# Test::Unit Rails - How to assert one number is greater than another one?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, assert, testunit

I am writing my first unit tests with Test::Unit and I have reached a point where I need to compare two numbers. Much to my surprise, I have discovered that none of the following were [available:](http://topfunky.com/clients/rails/ruby_and_rails_assertions.pdf)

```
assert_greater_than
assert_lesser_than
assert_greater_or_equal_than
assert_lesser_or_equal_than
```

Is this normal? How should I do it then?

Thanks

Answer (score 81, accepted):

Rather than provide a bunch of different assertions as you suggest, Test::Unit provides the method `assert_operator`, used like this:

```
assert_operator x, :>, y
assert_operator x, :>=, y
etc.
```

Answer (score 15):

How about this simple thing,

```
assert x>y
```

Comment: Assert() can almost always be used to apply a given test, but it should be a last resort, because it gives much less meaningful results in the event of failure.  In this case, a better approach is to use assert_operator.

Comment: I am getting an undefined method `assert_true'. Is it deprecated?

Comment: The actual assertion to use with a boolean is just `assert`, not `assert_true`.

Answer (score 8):

Here are some functions you can put in `test/test_helper.rb`

```
  def assert_gt(a, b)
    assert_operator a, :>, b
  end
  
  def assert_gte(a, b)
    assert_operator a, :>=, b
  end

  def assert_lt(a, b)
    assert_operator a, :<, b
  end

  def assert_lte(a, b)
    assert_operator a, :<=, b
  end
```

Then call like so:

```rb
assert_gt 6, 3
assert_gte 5, 5
assert_lt 4, 5
assert_lte 5, 5
```