# Does rspec have anything more specific than target.should be < 6?

Tags: ruby, rspec

http://cheat.errtheblog.com/s/rspec/ has for inequalities (such as less than or greater than)

```
target.should be < 6
```

Has anything better been created since the cheat sheet was created?

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "better"?

Comment: @Michael: Something like "should be less than".

Comment: Um, '<' means "less than".  That's what your example code already says.

Comment: Related question, but for test-unit: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5819760/testunit-rails-how-to-assert-one-number-is-greater-than-another-one

Answer (score 56, accepted):

This is still the accepted way to handle this test.  It's best to use >, <, and == in my opinion for numerical comparisons -- it's clearer.

Answer (score 74):

In RSpec's new expectation syntax, you would express it as:

```
expect(target).to be < 6
```

Answer (score 8):

If you just want to check it in a variable like `target` then `target.should be < 6` is the way to go.

But if you want to check a property in another object, like `customer.orders`, where orders is a collection of elements, then you could use the [have(n).items matcher](https://www.relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-expectations/v/2-13/docs/built-in-matchers/have-n-items-matcher).

Example:

```
customer.should have_at_most(6).orders
```

That is the same expectation than this:

```
customer.orders.size.should be < 6
```

But with a cleaner message